# How can I find the factor contributing to a prediction?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, tensorflow, python

I've developed a neural network which predicts if someone is diagnosed with cardiovascular disease. Is it possible to find out which feature is the main cause of the prediction? For example, when a person is predicted to have CVD, it should show that his serum sodium level is too high.

Comment: You seem to be looking for Principal Component Analysis (PCA)

Comment: PCA is just a dimensionality reduction technique, it gives you no hints whatsoever about feature importance for a specific prediction of a trained model. At best you can use it to preprocess the features before training.

Comment: what you're looking for are a bunch of techniques falling into the macro category of explainable AI, you can check a fair summary of these techniques in this  [answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/12870/which-explainable-artificial-intelligence-techniques-are-there/24138#24138)

Comment: In the context of statistics, what you want to do is often called inference, which is different from prediction. Inference is just another term for what many people in AI now call _explainable AI_.